# Call Asp.Net MVC action to load store in sencha touch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I am calling asp.net action from proxy to fill the store data. 
I am specifying the url correctly but on make get request to Action it is appending query string params to the call. This is resulting in 404 error. 
I am posting my code below,

> Asp.net mvc Action

```
public JsonResult SongsList()
{
        List<MusicFileModel> musicFileModels = MusicFileModel.GetAllMusicFiles();
        return Json(musicFileModels, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> Store definition in Sencha Touch 2

```
Ext.define('CloudPlayerUI.store.Songs', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    model:'CloudPlayerUI.model.song',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/Home/SongsList',
        param:'',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    autoLoad:true
}
});
```

This is the ajax call that is made.

```
GET http://localhost/Home/SongsList?_dc=1333338051329&page=1&start=0&limit=25
```

I am assuming that because, Action doesn't have any params which is being made my ajax call 
it is resulting in an 404 error. 
I am not sure the correct way of calling mvc action. Please let me know if I am going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

update:
I tried adding the same query string params to asp.net mvc action. Still it is causing 404 error. When I open the same url without any query string params in new tab it is returning me Json result.

Comment: Do you mean `GET` params are appended by Sencha Touch to the AJAX call? Why should that cause a 404 error?

Comment: Looks like a pure ASP.net issue. Not sure ST2 has anything to do with it.

Comment: Can you point me to any example of using ajax in an proxy call. ? Also what can be other choice for server logic. ?

Comment: Your Sencha code looks fine. I'm referring to http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax and the docs for JSONReader. The only thing you might try doing is adding a `root` property to your reader. I don't know anything about ASP.net and can't help you there; sorry. If the URL doesn't open in browser with the query string `GET` params, then it's a server-side problem, not an AJAX problem.

Comment: thnkx. I added root property and also the 404 error was due to incorrect url param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

The 404 error was due to incorrect URL config param defined in the store. Also I added a rootProperty to reader. 
This is how the proxy code looks like.

```
Ext.define('CloudPlayerUI.store.Songs', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
config: {
    model:'CloudPlayerUI.model.song',
    proxy: {
       url: 'Home/SongsList', //Changes to url
        type:'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'ResponseData' //Addeed reader property.
        }
    },
    autoLoad:true }
});
```

> Constructing return object in Asp.MVC action.

```
var results = new
                          { 
                              Success = true,
                              ResponseData = musicFileModels
                          };
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```